# How to create different section in angular template (html file) conditionally

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am constructing `three` different table as following.

> There is a lot of repetitive code in it.

The only different in each table is `studentPermissions[]` array which contain three objects for each student. So under each table i am just changing it for each student like `studentPermissions[0], studentPermissions[1] and studentPermissions[2].`

Is there any further better i can write same code in less no of lines?

```
<div class="module-container">
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr >
                    <td>Student</td>
                    <td>{{studentPermissions[0].SubjectName}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th ng-repeat="permission in permissions"><div><span>{{permission.Name}}</span></div></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="student in studentPermissions[0].Students">
                    <td>{{student.FirstName}} {{student.LastName}} <small class="" style="color: #999999;">({{student.Role}})</small></td>
                    <td ng-repeat="permission in student.Permissions">
                        <input ng-model="permission.Checked" type="checkbox">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr >
                    <td>Student</td>
                    <td>{{studentPermissions[1].SubjectName}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th ng-repeat="permission in permissions"><div><span>{{permission.Name}}</span></div></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="student in studentPermissions[1].Students">
                    <td>{{student.FirstName}} {{student.LastName}} <small class="" style="color: #999999;">({{student.Role}})</small></td>
                    <td ng-repeat="permission in student.Permissions">
                        <input ng-model="permission.Checked" type="checkbox">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr >
                    <td>Student</td>
                    <td>{{studentPermissions[2].SubjectName}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th ng-repeat="permission in permissions"><div><span>{{permission.Name}}</span></div></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="student in studentPermissions[2].Students">
                    <td>{{student.FirstName}} {{student.LastName}} <small class="" style="color: #999999;">({{student.Role}})</small></td>
                    <td ng-repeat="permission in student.Permissions">
                        <input ng-model="permission.Checked" type="checkbox">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was not sure about question title so please feel free to update it to make it more relevant with question contents. thanks

**Also, I have to show data for each customer in septate table. this is requirement**

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or plnkr link ??

Comment: can you do an outer `ng-repeat` on `studentPermissions`?

Comment: @ kaveman, yes i am giving a try right away thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use another ng-repeat?

```
<div class="module-container">
    <div ng-repeat="studentPermission in studentPermissions">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr >
                    <td>Student</td>
                    <td>{{studentPermission.SubjectName}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th ng-repeat="permission in permissions"><div><span>{{permission.Name}}</span></div></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="student in studentPermission.Students">
                    <td>{{student.FirstName}} {{student.LastName}} <small class="" style="color: #999999;">({{student.Role}})</small></td>
                    <td ng-repeat="permission in student.Permissions">
                        <input ng-model="permission.Checked" type="checkbox">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i guess you're absolutely right. lemme give a try before marking it answer. thanks

Comment: absolutely cool. works fine and code is optimized as well thanks